# Can't find maven in OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: maven

Nothing when I type:

```
$ whereis mvn
```

but I guess it is somewhere because from Eclipse I can select a pom.xml file and run it as maven build

Comment: The Eclipse Maven plugin probably has Maven bundled, and anyway it will call Maven using its Java API, meaning you probably don't have `mvn` in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Eclipse brings its own bundled Maven. If you want to use Maven on the shell, I suggest you install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then install Maven like this:

```
brew install maven
```

After that you should be able to use `mvn` on the command line.

By the way, to find out where `mvn` is, use:

```
which mvn
```